# Reference on dimension theory (commutative algebra)

Tags: commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

I am learning some commutative algebra and currently use Kemper's book. On the chapters on dimension theory, I find that sometimes the book is sketchy and hard to follow. Could someone please point out some good reference on dimension theory? I wish it to be easy to follow, clear, gentle and as detailed as possible.

May thanks for any attempt of helping me!

Comment: I suggest you read Atiyah & Macdonald first (not just for dimension theory, read the whole thing). Then maybe go to Eisenbud (Part II of that book is dimension theory, it gets as detailed as you want, around 200 pages of details distributed in 9 chapters)

Comment: @Hamed Thank you for your suggestion. I will check it out. Actually I also do not know why does our course use the book of Kemper instead of Atiyah...