# Reference book to study dimension theory.

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra, book-recommendation

I'm looking for a book to study Dimension theory, In particular I want a book(s) which covers the following topics:

> 1. Krull dimension and examples. Dimension of an integral extension.
> 2. Noether's Normalization Lemma and its consequences.
> 3. Graded rings and modules, Hilbert functions and series, Hilbert’s Theorem.
> 4. Hilbert-Samuel functions and polynomials, System of parameters, Dimension Theorem.
> 5. Dimension of polynomial rings over noetherian rings.
> 6. Normal rings and their characterizations and properties. Finiteness of integral closure

Please suggest me a good book(s) which covers the above topics. (I'm planning to do self study, so if any of the book(s) is intended for self study it's really good. Even if not, I hope I can do, so you don't have to restrict to books intended for self study). Thanks.

Comment: I would say, most good books on "Commutative Algebra" should be sufficient. See also the comments [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2900175/reference-on-dimension-theory-commutative-algebra).

Comment: I followed Atiyah for my basic commutative algebra course. It has a chapter in Dimensional theory but I'm not sure if that's sufficient

Comment: I think for each topic there are very good papers available. For example, for topic 5. there are great papers by Seidenberg (Pacific J. Math.), etc. This could be more effective than just some book. On the other hand, there are many theses about this topic. See the [master thesis](http://othes.univie.ac.at/40563/) of my student, for example.

Comment: Thesis seems to cover most of the topics. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome!